# How to use multiset to get associated list of records with JOOQ?

Tags: kotlin, jooq

I am trying to get a record (engagement note), along with a list of associated records (attendees). I want to store them all as records, but cannot seem to get it to work. All examples I've seen online of multiset just use a few fields rather than the entire record. This is also in Kotlin if that makes a difference.

See below for what I'm *attempting* to do, it does not work.

```
  context.select(
        ENGAGEMENT_NOTE.asterisk(),
        multiset(
            select()
                .from(ENGAGEMENT_NOTE_ATTENDANCE)
                .join(ENGAGEMENT_NOTE_ATTENDEE).on(ENGAGEMENT_NOTE_ATTENDANCE.ATTENDEE_ID.eq(ENGAGEMENT_NOTE.ID))
                .where(ENGAGEMENT_NOTE_ATTENDANCE.ENGAGEMENT_NOTE_ID.eq(ENGAGEMENT_NOTE.ID))
        ).convertFrom { it.into(ENGAGEMENT_NOTE_ATTENDEE) }
            .`as`("attendees")
    )
        .from(ENGAGEMENT_NOTE)
        .where(ENGAGEMENT_NOTE.ID.eq(noteId.value))
        .fetchOne()
        ?.map {
            EngagementNoteView(
                it.into(ENGAGEMENT_NOTE),
                it.getValue("attendees") as List<EngagementNoteAttendeeRecord> // This is definitely wrong.
            )
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`selectFrom(Table<R>)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#selectFrom(org.jooq.TableLike)) to return a `Result<R>`, instead of `select().from(table)`.

#### jOOQ 3.19 solution

The upcoming jOOQ 3.19 [to-many path expressions](https://www.jooq.org/doc/3.19/manual/sql-building/sql-statements/select-statement/implicit-join/) along with [implicit path correlations](https://www.jooq.org/doc/3.19/manual/sql-building/sql-statements/select-statement/implicit-path-correlation/) will make this super simple:

```kotlin
context
    .select(

        // You can use a Table<R> as a SelectField<R>
        ENGAGEMENT_NOTE,
        multiset(

            // jOOQ 3.19 many-to-many implicit join path correlation
            selectFrom(ENGAGEMENT_NOTE.engagementNoteAttendee())
        ).`as`("attendees")
    .from(ENGAGEMENT_NOTE)
    .where(ENGAGEMENT_NOTE.ID.eq(noteId.value))
    .fetchOne()
```

Note, the above also uses a [`Table<R>` as a `SelectField<R>`](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/sql-statements/select-statement/select-clause/select-clause-table/)

#### jOOQ 3.18 solution

In jOOQ 3.18, to-many path expressions and implicit path correlations aren't yet available, so you have to hand-roll the correlation. You could use a semi-join, for example, if your RDBMS supports correlating derived tables:

```kotlin
context
    .select(
        ENGAGEMENT_NOTE,
        multiset(
            selectFrom(ENGAGEMENT_NOTE_ATTENDEE)
            .where(ENGAGEMENT_NOTE_ATTENDEE.ID.in(
                select(ENGAGEMENT_NOTE_ATTENDANCE.ATTENDEE_ID)
                .from(ENGAGEMENT_NOTE_ATTENDANCE)
                .where(ENGAGEMENT_NOTE_ATTENDANCE.ENGAGEMENT_NOTE_ID
                    .eq(ENGAGEMENT_NOTE.ID))
            ))
        ).`as`("attendees")
    .from(ENGAGEMENT_NOTE)
    .where(ENGAGEMENT_NOTE.ID.eq(noteId.value))
    .fetchOne()
```

Comment: Amazing thank you, that has worked. My only followup question would be is there a type safe way of getting the attendees into a list? I'm currently doing:

                    it.getValue("attendees") as List<EngagementNoteAttendeeRecord>

Comment: It's already a `List`? `Result<R>` extends `List<R>`